# Chain linking animations with aframe.io

Tags: animation, aframe

Is there a way to chainlink an animation in aframe? I am trying to once clicked move a cube to a position, hold that position for x amount of time, then animate back to the original spot.

So far I have just 2 animations the second is beginning when listening for an animationend event. Problem is, then both animations emit an animationend which in turn triggers the second animation over and over. This approach doesn't seem to be right

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Curved Images</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Curved Images - A-Frame">
   <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <a-scene>
    <a-entity position="0 1.8 4">
    <a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls>
        <a-entity position="0 0 -3"
                geometry="primitive: ring; radiusOuter: 0.30;
                          radiusInner: 0.20;"
                material="color: cyan; shader: flat"
                cursor="maxDistance: 30; fuse: true">
        <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale"
             fill="backwards" from="0.1 0.1 0.1" to="1 1 1" dur="150"></a-animation>
        <a-animation begin="fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale"
             fill="forwards" from="1 1 1" to="0.1 0.1 0.1" dur="1500"></a-animation>
      </a-entity>
      </a-entity>
      </a-entity>

      <a-box id="orange-cube" position="0 3.5 -2" rotation="30 30 0" width="2" depth="2"
             height="2" color="#583C87" roughness="0.8">
             <a-animation begin="click" attribute="position" from="0 3.5 -2" to="3 2 -2"
                   easing="linear" dur="2000" fill="forward"></a-animation>
            <a-animation begin="fade" attribute="position" from="3 2 -2" to="0 3.5 -2"
                   easing="linear" dur="2000" fill="backwards"></a-animation>
      </a-box>

    </a-scene>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector('#orange-cube').addEventListener('animationend', function () {
    document.querySelector('#orange-cube').emit('fade');
  });
//document.querySelector('#orange-cube').emit('fade');
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can play animations by doing `animationEl.play()`. You could write some JS to trigger the animations based on the conditions you want. The declarative API (A-Frame 0.2.0) does not currently support animation sequences.

Answer (score 2):

A D3 approach.

Here is a [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/bryik/pen/jAYBGm) that demonstrates what you ask for (I hope!). Using D3, you can schedule a second animation/transition after the first finishes with:

```
.each('end', <function>);
```

I wasn't sure how long to hold the cube in its new position, if 1 second is too short you can change the delay by modifying line 19 (in milliseconds):

```
.delay(1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

A-Frame exposes the tween.js object so you can wire it up yourself.

AFRAME.TWEEN

https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/

I will be writing my own new animation components to hopefully deprecate `<a-animation>` tags which are limited and don't fit within the framework.

Comment: Wow. I thought the animation tags were great, I am excited to see the new version! So far I am loving everything.

Comment: They are good, but limiting. I want to use the component system so that they can be defined using simple `setAttribute`, be used with mixins (and therefore aframe-mss), and more easily add features such as timelining.

Comment: Holy moly! Just saw aframe-mss, very cool. Well, I will say one thing. I trust you guys because you know what your doing!

Comment: I got a start on the animations using anime at https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-animation-component , will try to add sequencing support.

Comment: Kevin, are they as in-depth as greensock?